# Default language of installations in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, language

I have windows 7 home in English, but some applications default language is still in other language, and some websites. For example when I type **google.com** the page is redirected to`www.google.pl`. How can I change the default language to English?

From what I saw  changing the **Location** and the **format** in **Region Settings** to **United States** should do it. But still some applications and pages are showing in Polish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for **Google** if you prefer to visit Google.com instead of your local domain, **Bookmark** http://www.google.com/ncr.
This is an alternative web address for **Google.com** that always takes you to **Google.com** without redirecting you.
And if you want to go directly to a specific country is as simple as typing it ie: *google.us, google.com.mx*

To change the default language some applications and installations.

1. Open **Region and Language** by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking
   Clock, Language, and Region, and then clicking Region and Language.
2. Click the **Administrative tab**, and then, under **Language for non-Unicode programs**, click
   **Change system locale**.  If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation,type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Select the **language**, and then click OK to restart your computer, click Restart now.

The **system locale** determines the default character set (letters, symbols, and numbers) and font used to enter and display information in programs that don't use Unicode. This allows non-Unicode programs to run on your computer using the specified language. You might need to change the default system locale when you install additional display languages on your computer. Selecting a different language for ***the system locale doesn't affect the language in menus and dialog boxes for Windows or other programs that do use Unicode***.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your settings, since you are opening the Polish version of Google, it will open in Polish.
Once you change to the English version a cookie will be saved in your computer and will always open in English as long as the cookie still exist.

Comment: Maybe I don't explain myself well, but what  I meant was that google is that I write `google.com` and it sends my to `google.pl`, the same for other pages the default languages is polish, and most of them have the option to change language, but it will be more simple to have it in english from the beginning.

Comment: They detect your IP address to know in which country you are, then they send you to a page in the language used in the that country.

Comment: Thanks you are right about google redirecting to you local. I found this alternative that sends you directly to google.com without redirecting you no matter the country you are http://www.google.com/ncr.